# difference in assigning value to a property of prototype directly vs .extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I came across two styles to writing same code in Java script and want to understand benefits or disadvantages of both.

Here are below :

```
options = $.extend({
    property1 : value1,
    property2 : value2,                
});
```

VS

```
options = {
    property1 : value1,
    property2 : value2,
};
```

while googling I found out below :
 `1.0jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )` An object that will receive the new properties if additional objects are passed in or that will extend the jQuery namespace if it is the sole argument.

but can any one help me to understand :
1. whats the benefit of of using $.extend?
2. and what does this line means above:
 that will extend the jQuery namespace if it is the sole argument.

Hope above make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First approach you used :

```
options = $.extend({
                property1 : value1,
                property2 : value2,                
            });
```

### According to the [Jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

If only one argument is supplied to $.extend(), this means the target argument was omitted. In this case, the jQuery object itself is assumed to be the target. By doing this, you can add new functions to the jQuery namespace. This can be useful for plugin authors wishing to add new methods to JQuery.

### Explaination

The options you will receive is jquery object itself. Your result **option** object will behave as Jquery Object and you won't be able directly access the key **property1** and **property2**. Because you have extended the **$** i.e the **jQuery** object itself.

You can then use option as you use **$** to perform DOM manipulation or other feature as which **JQuery** provides. Purpose of extend is to add additional props to existing object. But if you don't provide target, it assumes it as Jquery object itself.

So now,

```
  options.trim(" Hello World "); // outputs Hello World without 
                                //leading or trailing spaces
```

P.S.  Behaves like a **$**

### Basic Object Assignment

```
options = {
        property1 : value1,
        property2 : value2,
    };
```

Its just basic Javascript Object, which behaves normally. You can access the properties using the dot operator unlike in above scenario.

The same behaviour of above  can be achieved if you pass a blank object as first parameter as

```
options = $.extend({}, {
                    property1 : value1,
                    property2 : value2,                
                });
```

Now it will behave as a normal object should, cause you have just merged your blank target object with new properties.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive details. this really helped me to get things clear.